# ASP.NET sample website for a SaaS model?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm looking to offer a software product using the SaaS model. This
of course will require that I build a web site where customers can sign up,
log in, manage their membership and billing options, and of course use the
software over the web.

Can someone recommend a good ASP.NET sample site or other type of site framework
that I can use to quickly build out the software infrastructure for this
site?

In other words, I'm sure things like member sign up, log in, adding/editing
account/billing details and all that typical account/user management stuff
are common elements of web sites these days, especially those that use a
SaaS model. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. Of course the portion of
the site where I deliver my software as a service would be unique. But many
of the other functions are common and I prefer to leverage existing code as
much as possible.

I've read about DotNetDuke which sounds like it could work somewhat, but it
also sounds more like a content management system. I really am not
interested in a CMS type of site. Mainly I just want to build out the
infrastucture parts of the web site (as mentioned above) using as many
pre-made parts as possible.

Can someone please point me to some resources for this? Commercial solutions
are fine too.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend DNN, just from experience with it and based on your specific needs, but you could potentially glean some useful information from it. There are a ton of other open source projects available that could get you started in the right direction. [CodeCampServer](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/) comes to mind, and there's [a decent list of other open source apps here](http://www.tampadev.org/News/Details/ASPNETMVCSampleApplicationsOpenSourceExamplesTutorials) (some of the ones listed might be a little outdated; at this point, I'd shop for examples based on the MVC framework exclusively).

EDIT: Based on comments, [Chargify](http://chargify.com/) is worth looking at. It's is more of a 3rd party, recurring billing option, but worth looking at for a quick launch solution and allows you to focus on your core competency instead of the subscription/billing components. You could start with the hosted service, then migrate to their API implementation once your project has legs under it.

Comment: @Mannish - I am not necessarily looking for MVC apps and none of them you linked are SaaS based apps. I am okay with commercial apps as well but need a headstart with development.

Comment: I was really just making the recommendation that you target MVC apps, but take that for what it is. Beyond that, all of those applications include services related to membership and security that you'll need from a SaaS perspective, and feel they would take you further than DNN. Perhaps I'm not understanding your particular perspective on SaaS implementations, but I would call many of those applications SaaS, and would all give you some form of a head start. I hesitate to recommend anything commercial as I've always built my SaaS implementations from scratch (or re-used previous componentry).

Comment: @mannish - Basically, the sample site I am looking for a site that has different plans, ideally with subscription logic, letting users switch from one plan to the other, membership, login, registering and an admin interface to manage membership tables. I am not well versed with MVC so at this point I am looking for Webforms apps, but I guess MVC is okay too.

Comment: Gotcha. You should remove the MVC tag, it's confusing to those of us answering questions from that topic. You've already got another answer below that's MVC based as well. See my edit for a potential commercial solution.

Comment: @mannish -  I am looking for a ASP.NET equivalent of www.railskits.com/saas

Comment: yep, I'm familiar with it, but I not optimistic that you'll find it. I did my own hunt for something similar about 6 months back and came up empty. Good luck in the search, though. Definitely post back here if you find something.

Answer (score 2):

DotNetNuke has a lot to be said for it and as a CMS includes such things as signup/login functionality out of the box. I would suggest you take a look at it and the various third-party and open-source components available for it carefully. It is a mature product, well supported and can be easily extended by writing custom .Net widgets for doing such things as serving custom content/apps.

Good luck with it all.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about multi-tenant apps, right? That is that multiple companies share the same web site, but in airtight compartments (one company should not be able to access another companies info). SaaS is a much broader term.

Just google "multi-tenant asp.net mvc" and you'll find several examples.

One commercial product: http://www.techcello.com/

Comment: Yes, I am looking for 2 templates. 1 is much simpler for a B2C site that has users logging in and using features enabled as per their plan and with monthly subscriptions. The 2nd one takes this a step further and provides a single database for companies to sign up and each company would maintain their own membership, roles etc. I believe the 2nd case is the one of multi tenant app.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Microsoft-produced reference apps that deal specifically with SaaS concepts, and they come straight from Patterns & Practices team resources.

**Fabrikam Shipping**

Just recently published, Fabrikam Shipping ([online demo & source](http://www.fabrikamshipping.com/)) is a SaaS reference app with an ASP.NET MVC 2 front-end covering concepts such as Identity management and federation (STS), user-centric authentication via OpenID providers, SaaS Provisioning, remote administration, etc. However, it is built on Azure and uses Azure services, so some of the implementation details of what you might be interested in is abstracted away.

**Litware HR**

[Litware HR](http://litwarehr.codeplex.com/) is somewhat outdated (from 2007) but provides architectural guidance and examples of using .NET foundation technologies (WF, WCF), ASP.NET WebForms, and SQL 2005 for SaaS, specifically showcasing configurability features common to SaaS apps (data model configuration, role-based access control, workflow configuration, etc).

If you put the two together, I think you will have a lot to learn from and build upon.

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a SAAS starter kit on github available at http://yatendra.github.com/saasapp/. It might be useful to you.

Comment: Is this written in MVC? I see the backend is mySQL. How difficult would it be to move to SQL Server. Please add some screenshots to get an idea what the site looks like. Thanks!